# When is $\int_{x_1}^{x_2} [f(x)-f^{-1}(x)]dx = 2\int_{x_1}^{x_2} [f(x)-x] dx, ~\text{if}~ f(x)>f^{-1}(x) \forall x \in [x_1,x_2] ?$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, inverse-function

$Edited$ after  the comment of @Ninad Munshi:

The result $$\int_{x_1}^{x_2} [f(x)-f^{-1}(x)]dx = 2\int_{x_1}^{x_2} [f(x)-x] dx, ~\text{if}~ f(x)>f^{-1}(x) \forall x \in [x_1,x_2],~~~~~~(*)$$
holds for
$$(i):f(x)=\sqrt{x}, f:[0,1] \to [0,1];~ \text{however for}~  (ii): f(x)=x^3+x, f:[0,1] \to [0,2] ~ \text{and} ~ (iii) : f(x)=e^x, f:[0,2] \to [1,e^2]$$
it doesn't. Apparently, the reason could be that in this cases $(ii,iii)$, $f(x)=f^{-1}(x)$ doesn't have two roots.

What could be the the most rigorous reason behind $(*)$?

For an answer see the comments below.

Comment: It is not true in the second case. This property only holds if: $(1)$ $x_1,x_2$ are fixed points of $f$ and $(2)$ The graphs of $f$ and $f^{-1}$ are contained entirely within the first or third quadrants.

Comment: Thanks, yes in (2) it doesn't hold. Tell me if roots of $f(x)=f^{-1}(x)$, are also the fixed points or they are strictly defined as $f(x)=x$.

Comment: Those statements are equivalent